# Using ruby hash as constraints for selecting from a larger hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash of `conditions`:

```
{"age" => "52", "First_Name" => "Bat"}
```

And I have an array of `person` hashes:

```
[{"id"=>"1", "First_Name"=>"John", "Last_Name"=>"Doe", "Age"=>"27"}, {"id"=>"2", "First_Name"=>"Jane", "Last_Name"=>"Doe", "Age"=>"26"}, {"id"=>"3", "First_Name"=>"Bat", "Last_Name"=>"Man", "Age"=>"52"}, {"id"=>"4", "First_Name"=>"Bat", "Last_Name"=>"Woman", "Age"=>"51"}]
```

How do I get all the `person` hashes who match `conditions`? (In this case, it should only return the "Bat Man" hash.)

Comment: For posterity, it would be great if you could edit your question to make it clearer that you want a list of _all_ objects that match the conditions, and not only the first that matches (in which case, as suggested by @tokland, `detect` would have been the best choice).

Comment: thank _you_ for editing your question :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to get *all* the people who match `conditions`:

```
people.select do |person|
  conditions.all? { |k,v| person[k] == v }
end
```

Or if you are sure there will only ever be one (thanks to @tokland):

```
people.detect do |person|
  conditions.all? { |k,v| person[k] == v }
end
```

Comment: the "person who matches conditions" -> detect

Comment: I tried accepting earlier--it wouldn't let me, saying I had to wait a day. I wouldn't let something like this hang :)